# How to take screen-shots of map in web view

Tags: android, google-maps, webview, bitmap, screenshot

I got screen-shot of map from view view, map is showing properly but **markers are not showing** in screen-shot.

```
RelativeLayout rlShare; 
rlShare.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
rlShare.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = rlShare.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: what's the relationship between `rlShare` and the `view`?

Comment: web view is inside relativeLayout with list view, i want to late screen-shot of whole relativeLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your `WebView` is being hardware accelerated and markers are being drawn on the hardware level.

You can specify that the view has a software layer using [`View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE):

```
yourWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code it will take the screenshot of the view

```
  public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: I guess he is using already this code but the markers are missing after creating the bitmap

Comment: by using this map is showing but markers are not showing.